# Why does the limit for calculating the volume of a hyperboloid using cylindrical coordinates start with r = 0?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, cylindrical-coordinates

I have been asked to find the volume of a hyperboloid using cylindrical coordinates:

$x=r\cos(\phi)$

$y=r\sin(\phi)$

$r^2 = x^2 + y ^ 2$

The hyperboloid is defined as $r^2 = z^2 + a^2$ between $z = 0$ and $z = b$.

I set up the following integral:
$\int_0^b\int_0^{2\pi}\int_a^{\sqrt{z^2-a^2}} 1 drd\phi dz$

However the solution given has the following integral: $\int_0^b\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{z^2-a^2}} 1 drd\phi dz$

Specifically, the inner integral has lower limit $0$ not $a$. This doesn't make sense to me, because if the hyperboloid is drawn as a cross section with $z=0$ we can clearly see the radius is never 0, it starts at $a$ and continues to the upper limit defined above.

Infact, $r = 0$ doesn't satisfy the equation for the hyberboloid ($r^2 = z^2 + a^2$) for a non-zero $a$. The same is done in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385683/how-to-calculate-the-volume-of-the-hyperboloid-using-integrals) question without any explanation.

Why do/can we start integrating at $r = 0$ when $r$ is never $0$ and doesn't even satisfy the hyperboloid equation?

Comment: Say, you want to calculate the area of a circle $r=1$. You would do it like this: $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1r\,dr\,d\varphi$. Can you see now why the low limit is $r=0$, despite it can't suffice the equation of circle $r=1$?

Comment: @VasilyMitch Yes - it seems very obvious now.